# Select data from multiple existing tables dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tables "T1" in the database that are broken down by month of the form (table_082020, table_092020, table_102020). Each contains several million records.

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | date     | value |
+----+----------+-------+
| 1  | 20200816 | abc   |
+----+----------+-------+
| 2  | 20200817 | xyz   |
+----+----------+-------+
```

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | date     | value |
+----+----------+-------+
| 1  | 20200901 | cba   |
+----+----------+-------+
| 2  | 20200901 | zyx   |
+----+----------+-------+
```

There is a second table "T2" that stores a reference to the primary key of the first one and actually to the table itself only without the word "table_".

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| rec_number | period | field1 | field2 | field3 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 777        | 092020 | aaa    | bbb    | ccc    |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 987        | 102020 | eee    | fff    | ggg    |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 123456     | 082020 | xxx    | yyy    | zzz    |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

There is also a third table "T3", which is the ratio of the period and the table name.

```
+--------+--------------+
| period | table_name   |
+--------+--------------+
| 082020 | table_082020 |
+--------+--------------+
| 092020 | table_092020 |
+--------+--------------+
| 102020 | table_102020 |
+--------+--------------+
```

Tell me how you can combine 3 tables to get dynamic data for several periods. For example: from 15082020 to 04092020, where the data will be located in different tables, respectively

Comment: Fix your design. Don't store data within the table's name. You should have one table, with a column to denote the value of whatever `'082020'`, `'092020'` represent.

Comment: Why do you need to have multiple table in the first place ? You already have a `date` column in the table. Put all into one table and you can throw away `T3`

Comment: @DaleK I tried to implement this solution through the cursor, Selecting data and inserting it into a temporary table.  It works, but it's very slow

Comment: @Larnu Because about 5M records are collected for each month. and to make it easier to select data

Comment: *"and to make it easier to select data "* Then you should be able to do this operation easily, if it's so "easy" using this approach. ;) Clearly it *isn't* as if it was "easy" you wouldn't be asking this question. What is **easier** is adding `WHERE YourVarcharColumn = '092020'`, not having 10's of tables. Otherwise, look into partitioning. The *real* solution is to fix the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no good reason for storing data in this format.  It makes querying a nightmare.

If you cannot change the data format, then add a view each month that combines the data:

```
create view t as
    select '202010' as YYYYMM, t.*
    from table_102020
    union all
    select '202008' as YYYYMM, t.*
    from table_092020
    union all
    . . .;
```

For a once-a-month effort, you can spend 10 minutes writing the code and do so with a calendar reminder.  Or, better yet, set up a job that uses dynamic SQL to generate the code and run this as a job after the underlying tables are using.

What should you be doing?  Well, 5 million rows a months isn't actually that much data.  But if you are concerned about it, you can use [table partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) to store the data by month.  This can be a little tricky; for instance, the primary key needs to include the partitioning key.

Comment: Thanks! I came up with a solution: I created a stored procedure, and I pass two parameters to it: the period from and to. And I form a sql query in a loop